# Issue with running selenium scripts in headless browser in gitlab CI beacuse of chrome extension involvement

Tags: selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, gitlab-ci

I have an automation test suite which includes the browser extension loading. I want to run these tests in gitlab but as far as I read, the headless chrome does not support the chrome extensions.

I can't use mozilla firefox as the extension is not supported by firefox. Please suggest me a way so that I can run my tests with the extension in gitlab CI.

Thanks in advance!

While looking for the solutions, I read about xvfb virtual display. I don't know what is it or will it work in gitlab. I tried but it did not work.

Comment: Can you use Selenium with WebDriver and regular Chrome (not headless)? / How do you do the testing now? You should try to do it the same way, using Gitlab CI as a task runner, then update the post with what is not working.

Comment: The tests run fine locally in regular chrome(not headless). Can we use a regular browser instead of headless chrome in gitlab CI?